# Complex Analysis - Basic Converging Sequence proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm going through *Complex Analysis* By Joseph Bak and Donald J. Newman, and I've arrived at an example that seems a little confusing.

***By definition:***

1. {$z_n$} converges to $z$ if $|z_n - z|$ converges to $0$
2. $z^n = r^n cis(n \theta)$

***The example states the following:***

$z^n \rightarrow 0$ if $|z| < 1$, since $|z^n-0|=|z^n| \rightarrow 0$

Now, I can understand that $z^n \rightarrow 0$ if $|z| < 1$, as it would imply $r < 1$, and I understand how $|z^n - 0| = |z^n| \rightarrow 0$ as a result of $z^n \rightarrow 0$

However, I don't understand where $|z^n - 0|$ itself comes from. More explicitly; I don't understand how one arrives here from 1.

If anyone has any insight that could help clarify the process, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Take definition 1. and put $\;z=0\;$ ...it is *exactly* what is written there.

Comment: In addition to @DonAntonio's comment, in this example, the sequence $\{z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is defined as $z_n=z_0^n$ where $z_0$ is a complex number with absolute value less than 1.

Comment: I just added the index $0$ to distinguish $z$ in $z_n$ as a symbol of sequence and $z$ as   complex number which has power $n$.

Comment: @DonAntonio I figured plugging $z = 0$ would provide that, I just didn't understand the motivation behind it. From what I gathered, it's clearer if one starts with $|z^n - 0| = |z^n| = |z|^n$, then one can apply the condition $|z| < 1$, then clearly $|z|^n \rightarrow 0$, which further implies that $|z^n| \rightarrow 0$, thus $z^n \rightarrow 0$. Sorry for a redundant question